# How big is Isla Nublar in Jurassic Park?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world

How big is the island in the Jurassic Park and Jurassic World movies?

Answers could be in area or length of island.

Comment: "Answers could be in area or length of island" — I'd only accept circumference.

Comment: How about answers in square nanometers or lengths in lightyears?

Comment: Just to explain my hilarious circumference joke: [it's fractal](http://www.statsmapsnpix.com/2016/08/how-long-is-coastline-of-great-britain.html).

Answer (score 2):

According to [*InGen Field Guide*](https://jurassicpark.fandom.com/wiki/InGen_Field_Guide) the island is 22 square miles.

> It offers varied ecological niches within a relatively compact 22 square miles - perfect for a biological exhibit of live animals!

[image: Scan of page 6 and 7 quotes above]

Comment: Ahem - http://www.dinosaurprotectiongroup.com/reports.html ("*It would appear that these animals are still not safe from the intrusion of humans and, with dozens of species still fighting for survival on **30 square miles of landmass**, it is time for the tide to turn. It is time for humans to step up and do the right thing.*")